# Fetching Specific User's Profile Photo via Graph API in SPFX

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph, graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

How can we fetch a user profile photo through Graph API and display into Web part in SPFX?

Here is my function to call Graph API to fetch Specific user's Profile Photo filtering through their `UserPrincipleName`:

```
private image() {
    this.context.msGraphClientFactory
    .getClient()
    .then((graphclient:MSGraphClient): void=>{
    graphclient
    .api('/users/abhishek.negi@credentinfotech.com/photo/$value')
    .get((error,positionResponse:Blob,rawResponse?:any)=>{
    console.log(positionResponse)
    let binaryData = [];
     binaryData.push(positionResponse);  
    const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: "image/jpeg"}));
    document.getElementById('user-img').setAttribute("src", blobUrl );
    })
    })
}
```

Is their any way to display the API Response Image into a Web part?

In the API Call  `.api('/users/abhishek.negi@credentinfotech.com/photo/$value')` when removing "$value" at the endpoint:

Response at console

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('abhishek.negi%40credentinfotech.com')/photo/$entity",
    "@odata.mediaContentType": "image/jpeg",
    "@odata.mediaEtag": "\"5725BAEE\"",
    "id": "360X360",
    "height": 360,
    "width": 360
}
```

Without removing "$value" at the endpoint, I am getting null in the console.

Answer (score 2):

Change code as below, should work -

```
 this.context.msGraphClientFactory
  .getClient()
  .then(async (graphclient: MSGraphClient) => {
    let photo = await graphclient
        .api('/users/'+ mail +'/photo/$value')
        .responseType("blob")
        .get()
        .then((blob: Blob) : Promise<any> => {
          return new Promise(resolve => {
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
            // loading an in memory 
            let img = new Image()
            img.onload = () => {
              URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
              resolve(img)
            }
            img.src = url
            img.setAttribute('width', '24px');
            img.setAttribute('height', '24px');
            // loading an embedded html img tag
            document.getElementById(targetId).replaceWith(img);
          })
        });
       

  })
```